# Mixture of class and enum features

Tags: java

I have a situation where I define security roles for an organization. The choices are a set of known enumerated default values, and the possibility of any number of custom role. The roles define the permissions the employees have in the organization. For example, a user can be;

```
public enum Role
{
    Owner, Administrator, User, Guest;
}
```

However, the organization could also want its own custom roles (e.g. A PowerUser). I am looking for the best way to declare an object that has a known enumerated list of values (thats an enum) but with the possibility of provide any number of custom values (thats a class).

A naive approach would be the following (adding a custom enum value):

```
 public enum Role
 {
    Owner, Administrator, User, Guest, Custom;

    public BaseRole asRole()
    {
        //switch statement returning the BaseRole depending on the enum value.
    }
 }

 public class BaseRole
 {
    Set<Permission> permissions;
 }
```

The problem with this option is that the glue code will became very verbose if the enum value custom is selected. Since the custom value which holds all possible custom role would behave differently that the other values, every function that accepts a Role will need special glue to handle custom.

Ideally, something like this would probably be the best:

```
 public enum Role
 {
    Owner, Administrator, User, Guest, Set<Custom>;

 }
```

edit:

for reference, the user class would be

```
public class User
{
    Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Comment: What about having class `User` with `List<Role>` variable?

Comment: @libik, I want some type safety for selecting the default roles, with the ability to define additional roles during runtime. The user does have a List<Role> variable.

Comment: @libik better a `Set<Role>`

Comment: Use an `interface`. `enum`s can implement interfaces. Then you can have your `enum` for the standard roles but custom implementations can be added at some later point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I went with.

```
public interface Role
{
    String getName();
}

public enum StandardRole implements Role
{
    Owner, Administrator, User, Guest;

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name();
    }
}

public class CustomRole implements Role
{
    private String name;

    public CustomRole(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}

public class User
{
    Set<Role> roles;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution would be to look back in pseudo-enum implementations in the pre `enum` Java versions. E.g.:

```
public class Role {

    public static final Role OWNER = new Role("OWNER");
    public static final Role ADMIN = new Role("ADMIN");
    public static final Role USER = new Role("USER");
    public static final Role GUEST = new Role("GUEST");

    private String name;

    // getter, setter, constructor, toString(), hashCode(), equals()
}
```

So whenever a `Role` is required, you can use the final fields:

```
Role r = Role.OWNER;
```

And still define custom ones:

```
Role r = new Role("Cook");
```

With some caution, it may even allow for `==` equality checking between a variable and the predefined values, but I would advise against it (use `equals()` always).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you're looking for is an EnumSet?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html